# How to get values bound to ngValue in option element in an Angular 2 directive

Tags: angular, directive

I'm writing a directive in which I need to examine the value used with ngValue in option element. The directive sits on the parent . So, if I have the following HTML, is there a way to get to `item` inside directive `validatable`?

```
<select [validatable]="trigger" [func]="foo.bind(this)">
    <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item">{{item.s}}</option>
</select>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you seem to be talking angularJS. I don't think "directive" & "ngValue" are part of angular 2. And not exactly sure what you mean by "item inside directive validatable".

Maybe try something like this?

```
<select (change)="validateItem($event.target.value)">
  <option *ngFor="let item of items" [selected]="item.s == selectedItem">{{item.s}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: ngValue is definitely a part of angular 2+